# Absolute value inequality, difficult proof

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Prove that

$|x - y| \le |x| + |y|$

Let $x > y$ without the loss of generality,

$x - y > 0 \implies |x - y| > 0$

$|x| > 0, |y| > 0 \implies |x| + |y| > 0$

But how can you prove the statement? It is quite tough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** 
 Use the triangular inequality $$|x+y|\leqslant|x|+|y|,$$ with the substitution $y\leadsto-y$.

Comment: Okay =) I wasn't sure if I was allowed to use that property; anywho --> It makes sense. $|x - y| \le |x| + |-y|$ which is what is required =)

Comment: @Amad27 Exactly! ;-)

Comment: thanks, it easier to think in a different variable. $|x - u| \le |x| + |u|$

Answer (score 2):

$|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|, \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$.
$|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\leq |x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|$